# How to build python without threads and/or how to detect if python was built with threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I've built the following versions of python:
2.6, 2.7, 2.7.4, 2.7.5, 2.7.6, 2.7.7, 2.7.8, 2.7.9, 2.7.10

All with the following flags :

```
--prefix=/home/bdbaddog/tools/python-${x}-nothread --enable-shared --enable-unicode --without-threads
```

The advice I've found elsewhere sugguests that threading should throw and ImportError exeception when

```
python -mthreading
```

is run.  However for every version listed built as above I get the following output (though the order of the lines varies):

```
$tools/python-2.7.10-nothread/bin/python -mthreading
Producer-1.1
Producer-2.1
Producer-1.2
Producer-1.3
Producer-3.1
Producer-1.4
Producer-2.2
Producer-3.2
Producer-1.5
Producer-2.3
Producer-3.3
Producer-2.4
Producer-3.4
Producer-2.5
Producer-3.5
```

This would lead me to believe that threading is indeed enabled.
When I look at the install directories I only see the following notable differences:

- Only in tools/python-2.7.10/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:
  _multiprocessing.so
- tools/python-2.7.10/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py

  - See: https://gist.github.com/bdbaddog/2bef150ec4fbf016dc60

More info: python-config for each yields:

```
$ tools/python-2.7.10/bin/python-config --libs
-lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
$ tools/python-2.7.10-nothread/bin/python-config --libs
-lpython2.7 -ldl -lutil -lm
```

I need to know if threads are enabled or not so my python script can do different things in either case.

Have I not configured it properly to turn off threads?

Comment: Try `import _thread` in a python session ... if it imports then threading is enabled (somehow).  A subsequent `help(_thread)` will probably indicate its a builtin module.

Comment: _thread is python 3.x.  No module in threaded or non-threaded python build.  (Both yield ImportError: no module named _thread)

Comment: Apologies, in python 2.7 the equivalent is `import thread`

Comment: import thread yields no error in either --without-threads or default built python.  I do see that libpthread.so in a ldd of the nothread build though.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether you have threading like so:

```
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_config_var('WITH_THREAD')
```

This returns `0` if you don't have threads, and `1` if you do.

Alternatively, importing thread will raise an `ImportError` if python isn't build with threads.

Also, I'm able to duplicate what you're seeing. Just compiling `--without-threads` works for me:

```
seth@renegade ~/Downloads/cpython-2.7 $ ./configure --without-threads && make
...
seth@renegade ~/Downloads/cpython-2.7 $ ./python -m threading
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/seth/Downloads/cpython-2.7/Lib/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/home/seth/Downloads/cpython-2.7/Lib/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/seth/Downloads/cpython-2.7/Lib/threading.py", line 6, in <module>
    import thread
ImportError: No module named thread
```

But if I use your options:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/seth/tools/python-${x}-nothread --enable-shared --enable-unicode --without-threads
```

then threads seem to be enabled.

It seems that if you compile with `--enable-shared`, threading seems to get turned on. I'm not sure if that's a configure bug or by design.

Comment: Arg. I see the issue. It's picking up the system libpython2.7.so.1.0 which is built with threads. Thanks!